# Linked Server - Can't access user databases

Tags: sql-server, linked-server

I have 2 SQL Server 2016 instances, both patched at level SP1 CU8. I have created a linked server between them, with the following definition:

```
    USE [master]
GO

/****** Object:  LinkedServer [MyServer]    Script Date: 4/27/2018 12:58:24 PM ******/
EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedserver @server = N'MyServer', @srvproduct=N'', @provider=N'SQLNCLI'
 /* For security reasons the linked server remote logins password is changed with ######## */
EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedsrvlogin @rmtsrvname=N'MyServer',@useself=N'False',@locallogin=NULL,@rmtuser=N'SA',@rmtpassword='########'
GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'MyServer', @optname=N'collation compatible', @optvalue=N'false'
GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'MyServer', @optname=N'data access', @optvalue=N'true'
GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'MyServer', @optname=N'dist', @optvalue=N'false'
GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'MyServer', @optname=N'pub', @optvalue=N'false'
GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'MyServer', @optname=N'rpc', @optvalue=N'false'
GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'MyServer', @optname=N'rpc out', @optvalue=N'false'
GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'MyServer', @optname=N'sub', @optvalue=N'false'
GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'MyServer', @optname=N'connect timeout', @optvalue=N'0'
GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'MyServer', @optname=N'collation name', @optvalue=null
GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'MyServer', @optname=N'lazy schema validation', @optvalue=N'false'
GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'MyServer', @optname=N'query timeout', @optvalue=N'0'
GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'MyServer', @optname=N'use remote collation', @optvalue=N'true'
GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'MyServer', @optname=N'remote proc transaction promotion', @optvalue=N'true'
GO
```

After creating the linked server, it works fine if I query tables in the system databases. User databases, however, cannot be seen. The sa account, is of course a member of sysadmin on the target server. I also tried creating an explicit user in the target database.

I also tried making a user database the default database.